# Regular expressions(searching after particular index)

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regular expression that finds occurrence of a particular word but I want to search from an index(like the c# `IndexOf(string,index)`).

I tried something like this but I may be missing something

```
@"\.{index}.*WORD";
```

I try search the string `WORD` in the string after the index position.

It's about c#

Comment: I want questions to be a bit more friendly

Comment: Just curious... Why wouldn't you just match the regex to a substring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
/^.{number_of_char_to_skip}.*?WORD/
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your problem correctly you want to find the occurrence of string A after the first occurrence of string B.  Something like this should work:

@"^.*B.*A"